# IE 10, my js broken unless console is open

Tags: javascript, console, internet-explorer-10

My js code has been working for a few years under ie 9 / chrome & firefox.

I do have console.log scattered around my js code however even providing my own console.log does not help.

I have a list with each item having its own onclick call.

```js
<ul>
<li id="l_page0" onclick="ic2_selectPage(0)">Air Handling Unit 1</li>
<li id="l_page1" onclick="ic2_selectPage(1)">Air Handling Unit 2</li>
</ul>
```

With IE10, the onclick function passed index seems to get the wrong data, ie variable data looked up using index gives wrong contents.

```js
function ic2_selectPage (thisPage) {
 console.log("ic2_selectPage, Start - index= " + thisPage) ;
 if (pages.busyDrawing) {
  console.log("ic2_selectPage, exit as still busy") ;
  return ;
 } 
 if (thisPage == pages.lastPage) {
  console.log("ic2_selectPage, exit as same page") ;
  return ;
 } 
 pages.busyDrawing = 1 ;
 document.getElementById("s_selection").innerHTML= "page " + pages.page[thisPage].name ;
 console.log("ic2_selectPage, Setting status bar page name: " + pages.page[thisPage].name + "  thisPage=" + thisPage) ;
 if (pages.lastPage != null) {
  document.getElementById("l_page"+pages.lastPage).style.background = "" ; // Back to default
 } 
 document.getElementById("l_page"+thisPage).style.background = "#00ff11" ;
 if (pages.drawingsState) { 
  console.log("ic2_selectPage, hide open drawing") ;
  pages.page[pages.lastPage].svgObject.style.display = "none" ; 
 } else {
  pages.drawingsState = 1 ;
  document.getElementById("b_zoomin").disabled = false ;
  document.getElementById("r_drawing").style.display = "block" ;
 } 
 pages.lastPage = thisPage ;
 pages.maxWidth = document.getElementById("r_drawing").offsetWidth ;
 pages.maxHeight = document.getElementById("r_drawing").offsetHeight ;
 console.log("ic2_selectPage, pages.maxWidth=" + pages.maxWidth + "  pages.maxHeight=" + pages.maxHeight) ;
 if (pages.page[thisPage].svgObject != null) {  // Unhide as exists
  console.log("ic2_selectPage, Unhide existing image") ;
  pages.page[pages.lastPage].svgObject.style.display = "block" ; 
  pages.busyDrawing = 0 ;
  return ;
 }
 console.log("ic2_selectPage, Opening drawing: " + pages.page[thisPage].name + "  thisPage=" + thisPage) ;
 document.getElementById("r_waitloading").style.display = "block" ;
 // Create new region for SVG object 
  pages.page[thisPage].svgObject = document.createElement('object') ;
 pages.page[thisPage].svgObject.setAttribute('type', 'image/svg+xml') ;
 pages.page[thisPage].svgObject.setAttribute('data', pages.page[thisPage].image+"?check_304") ;
 pages.page[thisPage].svgObject.setAttribute('width', pages.maxWidth);
 pages.page[thisPage].svgObject.setAttribute('height', pages.maxHeight);
 pages.page[thisPage].svgObject.onload = function() { ic2_svgLoaded(thisPage) ; } ;
 var container = document.getElementById("r_drawing") ;
 container.appendChild(pages.page[thisPage].svgObject) ;
 pages.loadingTimerID =  setTimeout('ic2_svgLoadFailed('+thisPage+')',60000) ; // 60 secs
 //pages.page[thisPage].svgObject.onload = function() { ic2_svgLoaded(thisPage) ; } ;
}
```

If I open the console after executing the code the logging is just as confused.

If I click on the second item in the list, the code displays the correct text in the status bar (name for index=1) but fetches the image file linked to index=0.

Then open console (F12) and I get the following:

```js
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: 127.0.0.1:88
ic2_onload, instanceID=971506572
ic2_clockInit, Start
ic2_cookieInit, Start
ic2_fetchSites, Start
ic2_jqueryListSites, Start
ic2_buildSitesList, Start
ic2_jqueryGetBranding, Start
ic2_getcookie, Start
ic2_verifyUser, Start
ic2_verifyUser, Resp:1
ic2_verifyUser, Done
login.proceed, Start
ic2_fetchPages, Start 
ic2_jqueryListPages, Start
ic2_buildPagesList, Start
ic2_wizard, start - pages
ic2_jqueryCountAlarms, Start
ic2_pages, Start
ic2_wizard, start - last
trend.hideTrend, Start
users.hideUsers, Start
ic2_selectPage, Start - index= 0
ic2_selectPage, Setting status bar page name: Air Handling Unit 1  thisPage=0
ic2_selectPage, pages.maxWidth=1360  pages.maxHeight=903
ic2_selectPage, Opening drawing: Air Handling Unit 1  thisPage=0
ic2_svgLoaded, Start
ic2_svgLoaded, svgDoc=[object Document]
ic2_svgLoaded, svgDoc.readyState=complete   svgDoc.childNodes=2
ic2_addPoints, Start
ic2_addPoints, svgRoot.width=2000  svgRoot.height=1412.19
ic2_addPoints, myComps.length=164
pixelsScale = 0.9992886402004599
```

Which clearly showns (11 from bottom) that the onclick passes the index=0...  checking the DOM confirms that the clicked list item does indeed have the correct index=1.

Answer (score 1):

Internet explorer considers a website which has console.log statement being hit in it's code as a dev website and not production.

Once you are finished coding remove all your console.log statements and your app should work fine without the toolbar being open.

- All this is due to window.console being undefined when dev toolabar is closed. It get's defined when you open the the developer tools

If you absolutely need to keep your console statements then wrap them like this (I don't recommend you having console statement in production code):

```
if (console){
    console.log("Screen is overrated!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.   1) The if (window.console) tests TRUE in IE10 (with no console open).    2) Even if I kill the console by defining my own console.log function  the faulty behavior continues.

Comment: I have setup a temp. link to the website on my work PC.
http://purpleswift.selfip.com:88  The login / password is demo / demo (as prompted on the screen).   Press the pages menu item.   Then open either AHU 1 or 2,   press F5 to refresh and try again.   within a few tries you should get image AHU1 opening for selected AHU2.